# Rewriting / Redirecting request outside wordpress

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

I need Wordpress to redirect requests matching a specific url structure to another script than index.php.

I'm using nginx so i cannot simply add a rewrite rule in the .htaccess file nor do I have access to the server configuration file. So I guess my only option is to do it from within WordPress.

I tried the following, then saved the Settings>Permalinks to flush the rewrite rules, but it does not work.

```
function rewrite_action() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%template%', '([^/]*)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%title%', '([^/]*)');
    add_rewrite_rule( '^partners/([^/]*)/?', 'partners-output.php?template=$matches[1]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule( '^partners/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$?', 'partners-output.php?template=$matches[1]&title=$matches[2]', 'top');
}


add_action( 'init', __NAMESPACE__ . '\rewrite_action', 1, 0 );
```

Right now, it only returns WordPress's 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, to add rewrite rules in Wordpress there is the [generate_rewrite_rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/generate_rewrite_rules) filter. From there you can call the function [add_external_rule](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rewrite/add_external_rule/) (`$wp_rewrite->add_external_rule($rule)`) where you could add your rule which not maps to `index.php`. Unfortunately Wordpress will try to write this rule into the `.htaccess` file. But maybe [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/90550/77421) could be helpful.