# How can I add rewrite rules to a class-based plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm working on a custom plugin that requires a few rewrite rules.  I've followed the documentation but the rules aren't executing.  I've tried some variations but I keep getting errors.  This is an excerpt of what the code looks like:

```
if (!class_exists('CC_Forms'))
{
 class CC_Forms
 {
   private $options;

   /**
    *
    * Assign everything as a call from within the constructor
    */
   function __construct()
   {
     add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts',array(&$this,'cc_add_CSS'));

     // register admin pages for the plugin
     add_action('admin_menu',array(&$this,'cc_admin_pages_callback'));
     add_action('admin_init',array($this,'page_init'));
     add_action('admin_footer',array($this,'my_action_javascript'));

     // rewrite tags
     /*add_action('init', function()
     {
       add_rewrite_tag('%sign1%', '([^&]+)');
       add_rewrite_tag('%sign2%', '([^&]+)');
     });*/

     // rewrite rules
     add_action('init',array($this,'cc_rewrite_rules'));
     /*, function()
     {
       cc_rewrite_rules();
     });*/
   }

   // Rewrite Rules
   function cc_rewrite_rules()
   {
     add_rewrite_rule('^page/form/([^/]*)-([^/]*)?$',
       '/wp-content/plugins/cc-plugin/pages/form.php?sign1=$matches[1]&sign2=$matches[2]',
       'top'
     );
   }
  }
 } 

 if (class_exists('CC_Forms'))
 {
    // Register activation and deactivation hooks
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__,array( 'CC_Forms', 'cc_activate' ));
    register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__,array( 'CC_Forms', 'cc_deactivate' ));
    register_uninstall_hook(__FILE__,array( 'CC_Forms', 'cc_uninstall' ));

    // Shortcodes
    add_shortcode('form_selector',array( 'CC_Forms', 'cc_shortcode' ));
    add_shortcode('form_compatibility',array( 'CC_Forms', 'cc_compatibility_shortcode' ));

    // add_filter('admin_init', array('CC_Forms', 'cc_rewrite_rules'));

    // Initialize everything
    $cc_plugin_base = new CC_Forms();
 }
```

Any help to get these rewrite rules functioning is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any rule that doesn't point to `index.php` is interpreted as an **external** rule and gets added to `.htaccess`.

`$matches` array works only when second argument (`$redirect`) of [add_rewrite_rule()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) point to file `index.php`. External rules need to use the `$1`, `$2` instead of `$matches[1]`, `$matches[2]`.

Remember to flush rewrite rules after the change.

Comment: The server is actually running nginx.  I switched to '/wp-content/plugins/cc-plugin/pages/form.php?sign1=$1&sign2=$2' and added a $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true); to the end of it.  Still no luck - any way to verify if the rule has been added and just isn't firing?

Comment: You must manually add rule in the Nginx configuration file. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90544/how-do-i-add-a-server-independent-external-rewrite-rule

Comment: Ok, not my preferred approach.  What if I change the rule to use index.php so that WordPress manages it - is there a way to catch the redirect and "break out" of the standard WordPress structure?  I'd like to have the template load around the code, but I need to take over the page contents with this section of the plugin.

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/332319/custom-url-structure-for-custom-template/333267#333267)? Load `form.php` (which is page template, like *index.php* or *page.php* ) from plugin when visitor open `page/form/[sign1]/[sign2]/` url?